# Кто должен отдать данные в шаблон?

Tags: php, ооп, роутинг

Есть такой код в роутере:

```
$klein->respond('/[:name]', function ($request) {
    $reg  = new Reg();
    $reg = $reg->createUser($request->name);
    return $reg;
});
$klein->dispatch();
```

Класс Reg занимается регистрацией и может вернуть либо id зарегистрированного пользователя либо ошибку с указанием причины. Но зачем в роутер возвращать id или ошибку? По хорошему её надо во view вывести (view могут быть разные у успешного исхода и ошибки).

Вопрос: кто должен вызвать нужную view? у меня варианта 2:

1) Сам класс Reg вызывает view, передаёт ей данные и потом условно делает die() что бы в роутер ничего не вернулось

2) Reg возвращает какую-то примитивную инфу типа true/false а роутер уже в зависимости от неё вызывает нужную view, о вроде это не его дело...

Comment: Вы используете MVC? Можете описать подробнее вашу схему, если у вас не MVC? Если же вы используете MVC, я так понимаю model 2, есть ли у вас контроллеры и какие функцию они выполняют?

Comment: @cheops да я хотел бы использовать mvc но по какой схеме сам как раз пытаюст разобраться. В описанной мной схеме класс Reg() будет моделью, вьюшка понятно view, а контроллер где тогда? Роутер будет контроллером?

Comment: У вас то, что вы называете роутером, выполняет сейчас функции контроллера. Роутер обычно лишь сопоставляет запрошенный путь '/[:name]' классу контроллера и его методу. Т.е. на уровне роутера не должно быть дополнительной логики как у вас сейчас. Идеально, если бы все правила роутинга убирались бы у вас на один экран монитора. А уже в контроллере вы реализуете логику (возврат 403, если авторизация провалилась, редиректы, запрос модели и передача данных на рендеринг). Хорошо бы разбить "роутинг" на анализ роутов и контроллеры.

Comment: @cheops полностью с вами согласен может быть кто-то в ответе приведёт пример как должно быть что бы соблюдалось условие `Роутер лишь сопоставляет запрошенный путь '/[:name]'`